# Is past perfect continuous mandatory when you mention the duration of an action in reported speech?

Tags: past-continuous, past-perfect-continuous

He said "I have been working in the garden for 8 hours" - direct speech.

He said that he had been working in the garden for 8 hours. - indirect speech

Is "He said that he was working in the garden for 8 hours" also possible?

Answer (score 1):

> Is "He said that he was working in the garden for 8 hours" also possible?

"was working" is Simple Past Continuous. Generally speaking, that verb tense is a possibility.  However, you also included "for 8 hours" which corresponds better with Simple Past. Therefore, the following are grammatically correct:

"He said that he worked in the garden for 8 hours."

"He said that he was working in the garden, when he heard a loud bang."

and

"He said that he had worked in the garden for 8 hours."

It should be noted that each of these choices, as well as the ones mentioned in the original question, have different meanings. They are not exactly synonymous.

Comment: I don't see *He said that he **had** worked in the garden for 8 hours* anywhere.

Comment: I don't see *He said that he **will** work in the garden for 8 hours.*

Comment: But OP gives Present Perfect and Past Perfect *Continuous* (as well as "Simple Past Continuous"). There's no reason to introduce a *future* tense, but assuming the aspect being queried is "Do I need a *continuous* verb form here?", it seems only reasonable that someone should explicitly present the ***non-continuous*** Past Perfect form.